# How to rename an attribute in XML?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

i have XMl like

```
<record id="1" name="CustomerInfo">
    <field name="id" index="1" type="String"/>
</record>
```

i want to rename "**name**" attribute to "**match**" like

```
<record id="1" match="CustomerInfo">
    <field match="id" index="1" type="String"/>
</record>
```

Comment: Can you test the `setName` method and tell me if it works? I don't have access to Flash compiler now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a new field based on the old one and then delete the old :

```
var xml:XML = <record id="1" name="CustomerInfo">
               <field name="id" index="1" type="String"/>
              </record>;

// create new one
xml.field.@match=xml.field.@name;

// delete old one
delete xml.field.@name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [setName method](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/XML.html#setName%28%29): I haven't used it, but the docs says it will work on attributes too.

```
var xml:XML = <record id="1" name="CustomerInfo">
                 <field name="id" index="1" type="String"/>
              </record>;

xml.@name[0].setName("match");
trace(xml.toXMLString());

xml.field.@name[0].setName("match");
trace(xml.toXMLString());
```

---

Update: It works in Firefox e4x javascript, so it should work in ActionScript too. Try this:

```
var xml:XML = <record id="1" name="CustomerInfo">
                 <field name="id" index="1" type="String"/>
              </record>;

var names:XMLList = xml.descendants("@name");//all `name` attributes 
for(var i:Number = 0; i < names.length(); i++)
{
  names[i].setName("match");
}
trace(xml.toXMLString());
```